Temporary coolant smell in cabin when turning on A/C
I noticed that my car (2012 Volvo C30 T5) tends to get a coolant smell in the cabin for about 15-30 seconds, as soon as I turn on the air conditioning.  It does not manifest when only the blower fan is on, without the AC.
No overheating or missing coolant or loss of A/C cooling power that I’ve noticed… yet.
At first I suspected a leaking heater core, but the smell goes away after 15-30 seconds so that can’t be it, right?
Another important note, this car’s coolant tank explosively failed recently (cracked on top), which caused coolant to spray pretty much everywhere within the engine bay.  I didn’t bother cleaning up the coolant mess when I changed the tank, so could I just be smelling residual coolant from when that happened?

If the vehicle isn't losing any coolant, I'd suggest your thoughts on the expansion tank explosion is probably on the money.

Try washing down the engine compartment after a drive. The hot engine and careful washdown should not interfere with restarting after rinsing off dried coolant, oil and dirt. A nice warm day can help dry out the engine bay. However, if the coolant smell comes back, coolant may have been inducted into the hvac intake air ducting. Depending on where its located and access, cleaning with soapy water may help rid residual coolant in the intake duct. If rinsing isn't possible, dry baking soda powder (Arm & Hammer) sprayed, sprinkled into the intake with blower on low or medium speed should draw in powder, coating passageways. Baking soda will absorb and neutralize most odors in vehicle hvac systems.

I agree with washing down the engine compartment, but would do it cold, not hot ... the reason for this is if done warm (or hot after a drive) could cause warpage to engine components ... ask me how I know.

I washed my engine bay and engine, carefully, after a drive on a warm day, several times over the years. '03 GM car with electronic fuel injection. Personally, I am aware of heated engine parts. electronics (ecm mounted on the engine, various electrical connections, main fuse box, etc.  Personally, a hot engine sprayed with water, not hosed forcefully, will help evaporate water. I don't recommend it for everyone except those aware of the risks. In this case, a mild soapy water solution and toilet brush or something suitable to get into nooks and crannies should rinse off residual antifreeze.
